# How do you increase the timeout on an apache server?

Tags: apache, timeout, wamp

I am running WAMP on my pc. Works great. I have 1 php routine that reads 5,000 records from 1 mysql database and writes 12 times that number to another mysql database. I use the data from the 5,000 names and add to it to create the 12,000 records in the 2nd database. This works fine on GoDaddys servers but it times out after 30 se3conds on my local machnine when I test.

I researched the problem and found KeepAlive and KeepAlive timeout directives. I set KeepAlive to ON in the httpd.conf. I set KeepAlive to 60 but the inserts still timeout after 30 seconds.

KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 60

How does one go about increasing the time allowed for a bunch of mysql inserts?

The apache version is 2.2.17. The mysql is 5.1.53 and the php is 5.3.4. I have tried to run the updates on IE 9, Google Chrome v24, Firefox v18, and Safari V5. All timeout.

How can I keep it going until the inserrs are done?

Comment: Shouldn't that be max_execution_time in php.ini rather than something in httpd.conf?

Comment: @Kitet is right, set max_executin_time to 300 seconds at least. If you do not know where to find php.ini, you can find it out with phpinfo() function.

Comment: max_executin_time was set to 30. Changed it to 300 and then 3000 and rebooted each time. Still times out at 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the variable 
max_execution_time = 60
in your php.ini (Usually found somwhere like: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin )
and then restart all wamp services.

Answer (score -2):

I could solve my similar problem by adding to the .htaccess file:

```
php_value max_execution_time -1
```

Which will set the execution time to inifinity.

Of course, this should never be set in production mode. Just for scenarios like yours on localhost.